# How to avoid Material UI Select focus when option is chosen?

Tags: reactjs, material-design, element

I am trying to make an interface with a pair of `Select` and `Input` from Material UI components library. I want the current behaviour for my UI/UX in the next order:
1. User chose option from `Select` element
2. `Input`will be focused when user chose something from `Select`

You can see how it's works (see the second `Select`, because the first one is a native `Select`, and it's not suitable for my purpose):
https://codesandbox.io/s/l4nq3pjjrm

The first one in the example above works great, but I need non-native variant.

How I can do that?
Thanks.

P.S. Also, I found that there are another issues with that wrong `Select` behaviour, take a look for my github post for mo details. (https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11964)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

So if your problem is the focus after the value selection, try this:

1) Import MuiThemeProvider and createMuiTheme on your component:

```
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
```

2) Then Add this lines of code after your imports (override css):

```
const theme1 = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiSelect: {
      select: {
        "&:focus": {
          background: "$labelcolor"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

3) And for the final step, wrap your component that you want to edit with this code:

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme1}>

// Your Component here

</MuiThemeProvider>
```

I applied it on your code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/jlx2wnp6z3)

Comment: Cool, thank you, but I can't test your approach, it would be good for our community to provide a little example, if you can, of course.

Comment: I've edit my answer, because i'd done a mistake on my code. I also applied my example to your code, at the bottom of my answer. My Best Regards

Comment: Very helpful answer, thanks. One note -- in the latest Material UI 4.5.x the property seems to have changed, you need to use `backgroundColor` instead of `background`. Aside from that works great!

Comment: you saved me after hours of research. I manage to change the background on focus, do you know how to change the border of the input? I can't make it work with borderColor

Comment: What about specificity? It won't override default style without `!important` flag.

Comment: Works but spoils the Menu item position and styling, the other answer is perfect.

Answer (score 6):

For some reason the top answer didn't work for me. For anyone else facing this, you can also do it this way:

```
className: {
    "& .MuiSelect-select:focus": {
        backgroundColor: white,
    },
},
```