# How to remove greyed out color with clicks on material-ui chips?

Tags: reactjs, material-design, material-ui

Trying to figure something out with the [material-ui chips.](https://material-ui.com/demos/chips/#chip) When you click them, they hold a grey color until you click again somewhere else. I want to be able to click and have my `active` class and click again and have my `inactive` class. I can't figure out why there is a grey step in the middle.

```
<div className={classes.root}>
        {this.props.chipData.map(data => {

          return (
            <Chip
              key={data.key}
              clickable={false}
              clickableColorSecondary="white"
              label={data.label}
              onClick={this.props.toggleChipProperty(data.key)}
              className={(data.showing ? classes.active : classes.inactive )} 

            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
```

CSS:

```
  active: {
    backgroundColor:"#4054B2",
    color:"white",
     height:"20px"
  },
  inactive: {
    backgroundColor:"white",
    color:"#575b6e",
    border:"1px solid #8080806e",
     height:"20px"
  }
});
```

This image shows the grey part. You click, it shows grey on the button, then it finally shows the right color once you click off. I find this to be not intuitive. I want to click and have it simply toggle.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Cm60.png)

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with Select Component of Material-UI.
I guess that you can do the same with Chip Component,
just change the MuiIconButton to MuiChip (and maybe select to root also):

[Override MaterialUI Component Focus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51819797/10196400)

Let me know if that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Select component. I tried with the solution of Konstantinos and I end up solving this problem with 2 steps:

#1 Create a new theme

```
const theme1 = createMuiTheme({
overrides: {
    MuiSelect: {
        select: {
            '&:focus': {
                backgroundColor: 'none'
            }
        }
    }
}
});
```

#2 Wrap component with theme provider

```
<MuiThemeProvider theme={theme1}>
        <Select...
</MuiThemeProvider>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it and it worked for me. I used styled() Just set the

```
"&:focus": {
    backgroundColor: bgColor
}
```

Component example:

```
const AutocompleteChipSemiIncluded = styled(Chip, {
    shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== 'bgColor',
})(({ bgColor, theme }) => ({
    ...(bgColor && {
        maxWidth: '180px',
        padding: "15px 5px",
        backgroundColor: colors.primary.contrastText,
        border: `1px dashed ${bgColor}`,
        color: bgColor,
        '& .MuiChip-deleteIcon': {
            color: bgColor,
        },
        "&:focus": {
            backgroundColor: bgColor
        }

    }),
}));
```